# Outlook Error: user-defined type not defined referring to Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get 50 mails with Excel sheets per day. I want to add the first line of each Excel sheet to an existing Excel sheet located on my computer.

I first wrote a script that merges those sheets locally (I downloaded the Excel sheet and then run my script) and here everything works.

Now I tried to put the script directly into Outlook, so this is done automatically whenever one of those emails is received.

Originally I wanted to add a rule on which basis the macro should have been run, but this does not work. The solution I found was to call the macro in a subroutine within the "ThisOutlookSession":
[image]

This is the first time I am writing a macro for outlook, so I am unsure if I am passing the arguments correctly.

When my Modul2 is called, I immediately get the error

> user-defined type not defined

on the line `Dim wb_master As Workbook`, and on `Dim wb_email As Workbook`.

Here is a mini example of the code (here it simply adds the name of the file into the ID column):

```vb
Sub Merge_oewaReport(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim wb_path As String
Dim wb_master As Workbook
Dim ws_master As String

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb_email As Workbook
Dim j As Integer
Dim ir_last As Integer

wb_path = "\\swi56prof01\UserData$\heinreca\Documents\Outlook-Dateien\AllData.xlsx"
Set wb_master = Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
ir_last = wb_master.Worksheets(ws_master).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    FileName = objAtt.DisplayName
    Set wb_email = Workbooks.Open(FileName, True, True)
    fID = Split(FileName, " - ")
    j = wb_master.Worksheets(ws_master).Cells.Find(What:="ID", SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
    wb_master.Worksheets(ws_master).Cells(ir_last + 1, j) = fID(0)
Next
```

I checked the Tools>references Solution. The tick at Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library was already there.

I tried to define New Workbook instead of just Workbook.

---

Edit:
I decided to try the late binding method and changed some of my Dims:

```
Dim app_master As Object
Dim wb_master As Object
Dim ws_master As Object
Dim ic_last As Integer
```

Followed by:

```
Set app_master = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb_master = app_master.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
Set ws_master = wb_master.Sheets(1)
```

However now it returns an error

> Variable not defined

at the line:

```
ic_last = ws_master.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

It highlights "xlPrevious".

Comment: Add a reference to the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, since it's an `Excel.Workbook`. Also, you need a reference  to an Excel application instance. Outlook cannot for example execute `Workbooks.Open`.

Comment: The reference to the library was already added. How do I make the reference to an Excel application instance? Is it like this: Set wb_ master = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ? And how do I continue from here? Sorry, I really have zero clue on how to do this.

Comment: Microsoft Excel Object Library not Office.

Comment: Wellp... reading is key. Thanks, that worked!!

Comment: `Const xlPrevious As Long = 2`. `Const xlByColumns As Long = 2`, if you are late-binding.

Comment: Aha, interesting. Why do I need to define those? Up until now I never had to do that. Thanks!

Comment: With late binding Outlook does not recognize Excel terms. This is why Workbook has to be Object and Excel constants such as xlPrevious a number. For consistent late binding code, untick the reference, keep Object and change xlPrevious to the associated number. For consistent early binding code you can revert Object to Workbook and use xlPrevious as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When my module2 is called, I immediatly get the "user-defined type not defined" error, on the line Dim wb_master As Workbook, and on Dim wb_email As Workbook.

There are two possible ways to solve that:

1. Add an Excel COM reference so the types declared will be available to VBA. This is called early-binding.
2. Declare objects as Object if you don't want to add an Excel COM reference. This is called late-binding.

Read more about that in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) and [Early Binding vs. Late Binding: The Essential Guide for VBA Developers](https://nolongerset.com/early-binding-vs-late-binding/) articles.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I did already read about this, but didn't know how to implement it. I think I will go for late binding, but I still don't really know how to change my code accordingly. Could you help me with more detailed info on what to do?

Comment: In case of late-binding you declare all Excel objects as object in the code.

Comment: I changed all Dim xxx as Workbook to Dim xxx as Object, when I run it now it gives me a different error: Variable not defined and highlights the SearchDirection :=xlPrevious in one of the lines. I'll update my question above with the code.

Comment: Instead of using Excel constants you could use their numbers.